# jQuery - Hover CSS Element 1 change Elevement 2

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have two elements:

```
.navAbout
#slider
```

On hover of .navAbout, which is an A tag, I need the border color of (div) #slider to change to a specific color. Upon mouseOut, I need #slider to revert back to its original CSS declaration.

I have tried several codes. Here's my most recent:

```
<script>
      $(".navAbout").hover(function () {
        $("#slider").css({'border-color' : '#3bc624'});
      }, function () {
        var cssObj = {
          'border-color' : '#3bc624',
        }
        $("#slider").css(cssObj);
      });
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That looks approx correct. What is the issue you having?

Comment: but your are using the same color for both events..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this should help:

**JS**

```
$(".navAbout").hover(function () {
    $("#slider").addClass("coloured-border");
}, function () {
    $("#slider").removeClass("coloured-border");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.coloured-border {
    border-color: orange
}
```

Comment: Yes, doing it with classes is a far superior way – it's semantic and it means that a future styling change only needs to be made in your stylesheet. Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about manipulating the class! Great approached. I'll try this later tonight, but I'm 100% it'll work. Thanks everyone.

Comment: In theory, this should work, but it isn't. I've double-checked classes/ids for accuracy and messed around with the code a bit. No cascading issues either. Stumped. [link](http://macon.splicedev.com) @jakeclarkson

Comment: I'm sure you found it by now, but it's the nav. The purpose is to have the border hover along with the hover of the nav link so that the entire box turns the color of the hovered item.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I think you need `!important` on your styles. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/JE3M4/) I've knocked up; it may also give you some ideas about the JS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick in the direction you are trying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
      $(".navAbout").hover(function () {
        var slider = $('#slider');
        slider.data('style', slider.attr('style') );
        slider.css({'border-color' : '#3bc624'});
      }, function () {
        var slider = $('#slider');
        slider.attr('style', slider.data('style'));
      });
});
</script>
```

but the [answer of @jakeclarkson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527190/128165) is the correct conceptual approach to the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".navAbout").hover(
    $("#slider").toggleClass('borderColor');
});
```

Define a class with required border color

```
.borderColor
{
    border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would work, but you're setting the color to the same thing both times.

Also, I'm not sure if you are only alternating between two colors, or if the color of `#slider` is set in different places and could be anything. If it could be anything then you'll need to check what it is and save it so that you can set the color back to what it was originally later on.

Ideally you should just change classes [like jakeclarkson suggests above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527145/jquery-hover-css-element-1-change-elevement-2/8527287#answer-8527190) and avoid keeping style information in your javascript/css.

[**See this!**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xpnx/)

**HTML:**

> <a class="navAbout">Hover over me</a> <div id="slider"> and I'll
>   change</div>

**JavaScript:**

> var originalColor ='';
>
> $(".navAbout").hover(function(event){
>
> ```
>    originalColor = $("#slider").css("border-color");
>    $("#slider").css("border-color", "#3bc624");
> ```
>
> },
>   function(event){
>
> ```
>    $("#slider").css("border-color", originalColor);
> ```
>
> }
>   );

Read:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://api.jquery.com/css/