# jQuery - need to toggle one element when hovering another element

Tags: jquery, toggle, mouseenter

I'm learning jquery and I've been banging my head against this for a few days. I'm trying to create a page that has one large featured image and 4 small thumbnails beneath it. When the user hovers over the thumbnail, I need to change the featured image.

I'm having trouble expressing that when mouse hovers over A, toggle B. But when mouse hovers over C, then toggle D. What's currently happening is that all pshow classes toggle at the same time. Should I be using $(this) to toggle the current element? Should I be using a variable?

I've been searching stackoverflow for a similar question, but I haven't been able to find anything. Sorry if this is a duplicate. Is this the right approach??

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.pshow').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="story1">
    <a href="#"><h2 class="hover">Story #1 Text</h2></a>
    <img class="pshow" style="display:none" src="#" >
</div>


<div id="story2">
    <a href="#"><h2 class="hover">Story #1 Text</h2></a>
    <img class="pshow" style="display:none" src="#" >
</div>


<div id="story3">
    <a href="#"><h2 class="hover">Story #1 Text</h2></a>
    <img class="pshow" style="display:none" src="#" >
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527145/jquery-hover-css-element-1-change-elevement-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this...

Put the `class` into the `div`, instead of the `H2`

```
<div class="hover"  id="story1">
```

Then your Jquery...

```
 $('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
     $('.pshow').hide();
    $(this).find('.pshow').toggle();
    });
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/PC2Fp/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure **CSS** for that

For that to work you would need to remove the inline style and set the property in `CSS`.

As `inline styles` has more **specificity** compared to a style defined in `CSS`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="story1">
    <a href="#"><h2 class="hover">Story #1 Text</h2></a>
    <img class="pshow"  src="#" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{              // .pshow
    display: none;
}

a:hover + img {  // a:hover + .pshow
    display: block;
}
```

### **[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KfbTB/)**

Comment: Uh...that wont work...it will still show all....but also, just tried it in jsFiddle.  Didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector to select only one element with the class `pshow`.
You can do that like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hover').mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).closest('div').find('img.pshow').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: at least explain it so he learns how to do it again instead of just copy and pasting

Comment: `parents()` would be a bad option... if there is a surrounding div over all the story divs... it would select all the pshow images. you should use `closest()` instead.